# Why does BitSet require an explicit cast to be considered as an instance of Set[Int]?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

In the scaladoc, [`BitSet`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.BitSet) is defined as extending `Set[Int]`. So I thought using a `BitSet` as in instance of `Set[Int]` would work, but I get a type mismatch:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.1.final (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_29).

scala> import collection.BitSet
import collection.BitSet

scala> val b: Set[Int] = BitSet()
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.BitSet
 required: Set[Int]
       val b: Set[Int] = BitSet()
                               ^
```

However a cast works:

```
scala> val b: Set[Int] = BitSet().asInstanceOf[Set[Int]]
b: Set[Int] = BitSet()
```

So why do I need to explicitely cast a `BitSet` to a `Set[Int]` while `Set[Int]` is a super-type of `Set[Int]`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It turns out that your `Set` is actually `scala.collection.immutable.Set`.  So you can

```
val b0: Set[Int] = collection.immutable.BitSet()
val b1: collection.Set[Int] = collection.BitSet()
val b2: collection.immutable.Set[Int] = collection.immutable.BitSet()
val b3: collection.mutable.Set[Int] = collection.mutable.BitSet()
val b4: collection.Set[Int] = collection.immutable.BitSet()
val b5: collection.Set[Int] = collection.mutable.BitSet()
```

but not any of

```
val x1: collection.immutable.Set[Int] = collection.BitSet()
val x2: collection.immutable.Set[Int] = collection.mutable.BitSet()
val x3: collection.mutable.Set[Int] = collection.BitSet()
val x4: collection.mutable.Set[Int] = collection.immutable.BitSet()
```

and it turns out that the default import for `Set` gives you `x2`.  Import `collection.immutable.BitSet`, or import `collection.Set` (to cover `collection.immutable.Set`).

Comment: @jullybobble - You're still confused.  `collection.Set` and `scala.collection.Set` are _exactly the same thing_.  You mean `Set` from `Predef`.

Comment: Note: I removed my first comment on which @Rex answered because it was wrong and misleading.